# maintaining an ordered collection in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

My requirement is to create a table with the following structure

(user_id, score, rank)

user_id is an integer identifier (primary key also).

score is also integer value representing the score of a user.

rank is the number of users with score > the score of current user.

The entries to this table have to be regulated via insertion in another table. 
Whenever an entry corresponding to user_id happens in that table, 
the score variable in my table needs to be incremented by one and rank re-computed for every user_id.

Now the problem is the rank updation which is very expensive since I need to compare score of every user with every other user.

Is there a way I can create an ordered table where records are kept sorted on the basis of score and whenever an update to score occurs, that row moves up or down ?

The underlying DB is MySQL. What would be the best way to implement this ? Performance is the top most concern here and score changes very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Add property [**AUTO_INCREMENT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) to column `userid` and it will done automatically on insertion.
 No need then to supply userid value in `INSERT` query

Comment: @hasan, Actually user_id is the foreign key to my other table. Whenever an entry in that table happens, score will be updated in this table for the particular user_id